# How to add a custom driver to my kernel?

Tags: drivers, kernel, source-code, compiling

I want to add a custom driver to my kernel source.
But I have no idea how to do this.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a module you can issue the command

```
modprobe drivername
```

To see the status of modules

`lsmod`

To learn more please read [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/add-remove-list-linux-kernel-modules/)

Also you can read [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/) and [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29445&seqNum=6)

Comment: You are very welcome. I hope it satisfied your needs.tc